# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

Tags: php

I have a alexa rank checker script. Sometimes I am getting this error;

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function attributes() on a
>   non-object in /home/trackman/public_html/scan.php on line 14

On my script, line 13 and 14 are

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
$rank=(int)$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT;
```

I have tried this but the problem still occurs. What is the correct way to fix this problem ?

```
if (strlen($rank)<1) { $rank = "unknown"; }
```

Comment: This [works fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VaHXwA) for me. Maybe it has something to do with your URL? Can you show us the URL you're using to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When given URL is **NOT** valid, then there will be no data for `$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY`. so, you have to check it before using it.

```
if($url){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);

    if($xml  &&  $xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY ){
        $rank=(int)$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT;
    }else{
        echo "Not Valid XML";
    }
}else{
    echo "URL NOT Found";
}
```